# How do you randomly choose from a list multiple times in a quiz (10 times)?

Tags: python-3.x

import random
questions = ("4 + 2", "4 - 2", "3 * 3", "3 + 2", "5 * 2", "4 + 3", "9 - 3", "4 * 2", "1 + 2", "9 - 2")
question = random.choice(questions)

Comment: quietly. there's no need to shout in ALL CAPS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get X deterrent options randomly, you can first change the order of your array randomly and then pick one by one.